# Sample/Demo Database for SharePoint 2010

Tags: database, content-database

I'm looking for a sample/demo database for SharePoint 2010 in order to be able to demo SharePoint. Does anyone know of such a thing? Ideally it should have already created and populated lists and documents.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

There is an information worker download of a complete environment from Microsoft. This includes a pre-populated sample AD, documents, lists, libraries, profiles, etc. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjohnson/archive/2011/09/15/2010-information-worker-demonstration-and-evaluation-virtual-machine-sp1.aspx

Comment: I'm looking for just the database. I already have SharePoint installed

Comment: for SharePoint 2010

Comment: There isn't "just a database" to my knowledge, the MS VMs are the route to go.

Comment: A "sample" database by itself would likely have far too many dependencies on features and farm structure to be useful. If you need a full demonstration environment, I'd look to one of the MS offered VMs.

Comment: Not to mention dependencies on users that don't exist in your environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you need some SharePoint 2010 demo, check this out http://demoshowcasesuite.com/Theme/ThemePage/sharepoint2010

Please note that these are not actual SharePoint sites.